# Call v-on:click after append html in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can I have call onclick when after append html in vuejs, I using vue-append

```
this.html = '<div id="'+folderData[key].id+'" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="nav-link" style="color:black" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+textTooltip+'"> '+ 
                        '<div class="info-box '+back+'">'+
                            '<span v-on:click="gofolder('+folderData[key].id+')" class="info-box-icon bg-success '+icon+'"></span>' +
                            '<div v-on:click="gofolder('+folderData[key].id+')" class="info-box-content">' + textName + '</div>' +
                            checkbox +
                        '</div>'+
                    '</a>' + 
                '</div>'

<template>
<div v-append.sync="html" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pb-filemng-template-body row">
                </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just listen to `@appended` event?

```js
<div v-append.sync="html" @appended="onClickHandler" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pb-filemng-template-body row"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, but I did using v-for to load it, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I using v-for and an array to load, problem solved!
Firstly, I will not using vue-append and create a frames html and using v-for to create a list follow array data, because my list data will changes if I click in button
Ex:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 pb-filemng-template-body row">
 <div :id="item.id" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="color:black" data-toggle="tooltip" :title="item.tooltip"> 
        <div class="info-box">
            <span @click="gofolder(item.id)" :class="item.icon"></span>
                <div @click="gofolder(item.id)" class="info-box-content">{{item.textName}}</div>
                <input v-if="item.checkbox === true" type="checkbox" class="" value="">
                 </div>
             </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

specifically here:
v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"

after, I can call event onclick on buttons then not be afraid it will take the wrong value

Comment: Hi!  It is unclear what you mean by this. Others which find your answer can learn from it if you explain what you did. Can you share code of the fix you found yourself?

Comment: Ok bro, let me edit it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).